# Parsing JSON string from Python to .NET C# WPF

Tags: c#, python, .net, json, wpf

I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have two pieces of code and there is a missing link which I'm hoping someone can fill in. I'm new to both platforms and I don't have much experience with back-end nor with web architecture.

So below is the first bit of code, it's an adapted python server and it shows me a formatted JSON string when I enter http://localhost:8000 into the browser. This is great. It's what I want to see.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Save this file as server.py
>>> python server.py 0.0.0.0 8001
serving on 0.0.0.0:8001

or simply

>>> python server.py
Serving on localhost:8000

You can use this to test GET and POST methods.

"""

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging
import cgi
import sys
import json
import simplejson
import time


if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
    I = sys.argv[1]
elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
    PORT = int(sys.argv[1])
    I = ""
else:
    PORT = 8000
    I = ""


current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.warning("======= GET STARTED =======")
        logging.warning(self.headers)
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        logging.warning("======= POST STARTED =======")
        logging.warning(self.headers)

        data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
        #print "data_string: "
        #print data_string
        data = simplejson.loads(data_string)
        #print "json data: "
        #print data

        response = {}
        response = {"time": current_milli_time()}

        # Send a repsonse
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(data))



Handler = ServerHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "@rochacbruno Python http server version 0.1 (for testing purposes only)"
print "Serving at: http://%(interface)s:%(port)s" % dict(interface=I or "localhost", port=PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have a WPF/C# Application which contains a background worker and I have previously used this to get JSON string from a REST service.

```
public void getData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    var url = "http://localhost:xxxx/";
    var syncClient = new WebClient();

    while (true)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
}
```

So I pretty much need some direction on how to proceed, how do I get the JSON string into my WPF/C# Application? I hope this is clear enough, let me know if you need more info.

Edit: I have a feeling I need to get the current python server to post to another server which is RESTful which I can then HTTP GET the JSON string.

Cheers!

Comment: What is the value of `content` after this line? `var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);` ?

Comment: Convert JSON to C# object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: @ArghyaC If I assign `localhost:8000` to `var url`, it'll just return me the html markup, no JSON string.

Comment: @Gilang The problem is I'm not getting the JSON string in my C# Application.

Comment: It seems that the python server response JSON only when POST but not GET, I don't understand why your browser shows JSON.

Comment: @Diryboy could it be posting to itself? (might sound silly) and how would I get the server to respond to a GET? How would I change this?

Comment: Remove the `do_GET` method and rename the `do_POST` to `do_GET`?

Comment: @Diryboy I'll give that a go :)